# Proper way to test if server is up in Java?

Tags: java, android, connection, ping

What would be the proper way to simply see if a connection to a website/server can be made? I want this for an application I am coding that will just alert me if my website goes offline.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a standalone or web application?

Comment: @KaipaMSarma Actually this will be in my Android application, but I wasn't sure that was relevant so I didn't include it.

Comment: i added andriod tag also, so that people who already worked on this in andriod can view this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an HttpURLConnection to send a request and check the response body for text that is unique to that page (rather than just checking to see if there's a response at all, just in case an error or maintenance page or something is being served).

[Apache Commons](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) has a library that removes a lot of the boiler plate of making Http requests in Java.

I've never done anything like this specifically on Android, but I'd be surprised if it's any different.

Here's a quick example:

```
URL url = new URL(URL_TO_APPLICATION);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream); // You can read the stream however you want. Scanner was just an easy example
boolean found = false;
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String next = scanner.next();
    if(TOKEN.equals(next)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(found) {
    doSomethingAwesome();
} else {
    throw aFit();
}
```

Comment: Got confused with the first bit there as it wasn't at all relative xD Regardless, I will try an HttpConnection. Is there a better way just to see if a connection can be established instead of having to check the page for specific text?

Comment: Sorry, removed the confusing part. As far as checking if a connection can be established, `connection.getInputStream()` will throw an IOException if it can't establish a connection. So if you're only interested in being able to connect you can stop there. But if you want to make sure the correct page is being served you can read the body like I did in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You want to also set the connection timeout using `setConnectTimeout(int timeout)` and `setReadTimeout(int timeout)`. Otherwise the code might hang for a long time waiting for a non-responding server to reply.