# check server is available in network or not, using JSCH

Tags: java, mongodb, jsch

I'm using `JSCH lib` to execute some `mongodb` commands on remote machine, I have a program which has three methods those are

- `connect(serverIP, userName, password)` : it will connect to server and there is line

  `session.connect()` throwing below exceptions

`If invalid credentails: JschException:Auth Fail`,

```
If SSH is not enabled in server :JschException:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused



If server is not in network: JschException:java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

- `executeCommand(command)`: it will execute the command and print result
- `disconnect()` : it will disconnect from server.

I've attached the code below of three methods.

Question : If we use `session.connect()` without knowing server is available in network or not,its throwing Exception `JschException:NotRouteToHostException`.

Is there any way to validate server is available in network or not, Instead of getting exception?

If yes how can we do validate?

```
 public void connect(String serverIP, String serverUserName, String password ){
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            try {
                session = jsch.getSession(serverUserName, serverIP, 22);
            } catch (JSchException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            session.setPassword(password);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            try {
                session.connect();
                
            } catch (JSchException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    }
```

```
public StringBuffer executeCommand(String script) throws JSchException, IOException{
    String sudo_pass = "test";
    ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand( script);

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    channel.connect();
    out.write((sudo_pass + "\n").getBytes());
    out.flush();

    StringBuffer commandResult = new StringBuffer();
    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0)
                break;
            commandResult.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            Logger.of(LoggerConstants.AUTOMATTER_LOGGER).debug(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            Logger.of(LoggerConstants.AUTOMATTER_LOGGER).info(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            //System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            //System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            System.out.println(ee);
        }
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    System.out.println("Sudo disconnect");
    return commandResult;
}

public void disconnect(){
    session.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with just handling the exception,  java.net.NoRouteToHostException?

`} catch(NoRouteToHostException nhex) {
    // If it throws the exception you know the server isn't available
} catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}`

Comment: Based on exceptions doing validation is not good I'm thinking (I don't know correct or wrong),  I'm excepting Boolean validation like isServerReachable() or something else except Exception validation.     I'm going to make an API, in that above functionality will be there, at API level I can't not handle exception, I can throw.

Comment: Here's the function you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147352/checking-if-server-is-online-from-java-code.